# Ubuntu server - adduser and create home directory structure without logging in

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to create a new user for an app (a standard user because it requires a user directory structure).  However, I noticed adduser only creates the user home directory structure after the first login of that user.

I only plan to use the account with su to run the app.  Is there any way I can  create the user directories without logging in remotely first?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create the home directory when creating the user with no login needed:

```
useradd -m username
```

In the `Debian/Ubuntu/Mint` family, `adduser` and `useradd` are separate commands but in the `Fedora/RHEL/CentOS` family, `/usr/sbin/adduser` is a symlink to `/usr/sbin/useradd` and in OpenSuse, `adduser` doesn't exist by default.

Comment: `useradd` is the standard Linux program to add users, included with shadow-utils. It takes command line options. All distros will have it. `adduser` is a Debian-specific script that interactively asks the user for the new user's information.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know. I was just explaining that as he's using Ubuntu, it's better to use `useradd` whereas in the Fedora family or OpenSuse or SLES, it wouldn't make a difference because `adduser` is a symlink or just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The `adduser` Perl script seems to only create the home directory without copying files from the `/etc/skel` directory when the user to create is marked with `--system` as a system user.

```
# adduser --system --home /var/lib/serviceuser serviceuser
Adding system user `serviceuser' (UID 130) ...
Adding new user `serviceuser' (UID 130) with group `nogroup' ...
Creating home directory `/var/lib/serviceuser' ...

root@stimpy:~# ll /var/lib/serviceuser/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 serviceuser nogroup 4096 Jun  1 13:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x 79 root        root    4096 Jun  1 13:29 ../
```

Now let's delete the user and recreate it as a normal user.

```
# userdel -r serviceuser
userdel: serviceuser mail spool (/var/mail/serviceuser) not found

# adduser  --home /var/lib/serviceuser serviceuser
Adding user `serviceuser' ...
Adding new group `serviceuser' (1003) ...
Adding new user `serviceuser' (1003) with group `serviceuser' ...
Creating home directory `/var/lib/serviceuser' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
...

# ll /var/lib/serviceuser/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  2 serviceuser serviceuser 4096 Jun  1 13:25 ./
drwxr-xr-x 79 root        root        4096 Jun  1 13:25 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 serviceuser serviceuser  220 Jun  1 13:25 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 serviceuser serviceuser 3771 Jun  1 13:25 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 serviceuser serviceuser 8980 Jun  1 13:25 examples.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 serviceuser serviceuser  807 Jun  1 13:25 .profile
```

---

You could either copy the `/etc/skel` directory, which is normally used for this, manually with the command as follows.

```
rsync -axHAX --owner=serviceuser --group=nogroup /etc/skel/ /var/lib/serviceuser/
```

But I would recommend to also configure a group for the `serviceuser`, not sure if you did this. But `adduser` seems also to skip the creation of a dedicated group.

---

Second and maybe better option would be to use `useradd` to create your user. This will also create a user home based on `/etc/skel` and will create a dedicated group for the system user.

```
# userdel -r serviceuser
userdel: serviceuser mail spool (/var/mail/serviceuser) not found

# useradd --system --create-home --home-dir /var/lib/serviceuser serviceuser

# ll /var/lib/serviceuser/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  2 serviceuser serviceuser 4096 Jun  1 13:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 79 root        root        4096 Jun  1 13:35 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 serviceuser serviceuser  220 Apr  4  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 serviceuser serviceuser 3771 Apr  4  2018 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--  1 serviceuser serviceuser 8980 Apr 16  2018 examples.desktop
-rw-r--r--  1 serviceuser serviceuser  807 Apr  4  2018 .profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 19.10:

`useradd --help`

The options are:

- -m, --create-home             create the user's home directory
- -M, --no-create-home          do not create the user's home directory